# Re-entering Canada after a trip to Europe with my visa sent for amendment

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, borders

I am a temporary resident living in Canada under a study permit visa. But due to a mistake on the visa, I must send it to Ottawa to get it fixed. That process takes a while. In the meantime, I have to travel to Europe and I am worried about coming back to Canada while the visa is still in Ottawa being processed because I don't know if they will allow me to enter as a student anymore. I am planning to bring a copy of the study permit, but still don't know.

I've been looking for similar questions and it seems like entering as a tourist is not a good solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you're worried about coming back with the amended visa in your passport ?

Comment: I'm worried about coming back with the visa still in Ottawa being fixed.

Comment: How can you travel to Europe if your passport is in Ottawa ? Do you have dual citizenship ?

Comment: I only need to send the visa and they'll fix it. I have my passport with me. I have Spanish citizenship.

Comment: Oh I didn't know they did that, interesting. When you sent the visa for amendment, did they send any confirmation or acknowledgement ?

Comment: I haven't sent it yet, but i don't think they'll send anything back. If they did, are you suggesting to present that to the customs agent?

Comment: It could provide him with an "official" explanation of your situation and the reason you didn't enter as a tourist. My opinion, not sure that'll work

Comment: How serious is the visa mistake? Presumably bit got you into Canada the first time. Can you delay getting the visa fixed until after your Europe trip?

Comment: Did you ask the office in Ottawa?  Presumably they'll be able to tell you whether it is possible for you to travel out of the country while they have your visa, and, if so, what the procedure would be.

Comment: @DJClayworth, that's my first option, to send the visa after my trip.

Comment: @phoog, I'll try calling them and see.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after a couple of calls to the CIC Call Center (+1-888-242-2100), all I need is a photocopy of my current study permit and a photocopy of the application form that I'm using to get it fixed. I might have interesting times at the the customs, but apparently it will be OK.

The important point here is that regardless of whether I physically have the study permit with me or not, I still have a legal status in Canada.